# C GTK - SIGSEGV when trying to get index number of last item in TreeView

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gtk

I'm trying to get the index value of a selected item in a GTK TreeView in order to use that index to remove that value from a matching array of values. My code does this successfully for all items in the TreeView except the last one in the list. I get this error when trying to remove the last item:

```
(SDS-CW:32229): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 00:07:38.494: gtk_list_store_get_path: assertion 'iter->stamp == priv->stamp' failed

(SDS-CW:32229): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 00:07:38.494: gtk_tree_path_get_indices: assertion 'path != NULL' failed
```

Here is my code:

```
void remove_hash(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data) {

    struct data *dataStruct = user_data;

    GtkListStore *store;
    GtkTreeModel *model;
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GtkTreePath *path;
    GtkTreeSelection *selectedHash = dataStruct->selectedHash;
    int removeIndex;

    store = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list)));
    model = gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list));

    if (gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first(model, &iter) == FALSE) {
        return;
    }

    if (gtk_tree_selection_get_selected(GTK_TREE_SELECTION(selectedHash), &model, &iter)) {
        gtk_list_store_remove(store, &iter);
    }

    path = gtk_tree_model_get_path(model, &iter);   <-- This appears to be returning NULL
    removeIndex = *gtk_tree_path_get_indices(path) + 1;   <-- Error occurs here, I believe

    g_print("Remove Index: %i\n", removeIndex);
    g_print("Remove Hash: %s\n", dataStruct->queuedHashes[removeIndex][0]);

    // Function continues below, but error occurs above
```

Does anyone have any idea where I may be going wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If the last item is selected, `gtk_list_store_remove` invalidates `iter`. I think you need to obtain removeIndex before calling gtk_list_store_remove.

Comment: @JohnKoch Ah yes, I'm an idiot, should've spotted that one. I was thinking it was far more complex that it needed to be. Thank you! Can you post as an answer so I can accept as the solution for your rep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Gtk3 [doc](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html#gtk-list-store-remove), `gtk_list_store_remove`

> Removes the given row from the list store. After being removed, iter is set to be the next valid row, or invalidated if it pointed to the last row in list_store .

You need to obtain `removeIndex` before calling gtk_list_store_remove.